# find div inside a plugin with className and add another class to it in react

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I want to find a div that has been rendered by react-date-range which has a className of **rdrDateRangePickerWrapper** and add another class to it. but currently, it's not working, is there any other way to do this?

this is the part of the code,

```
<div>
  <i
    role="button"
    className="far fa-calendar-alt"
    onClick={() => {
      !openDistributionDatepicker && setOpenIngestDatepicker((prev) => !prev);
      document
        .getElementsByClassName("rdrDateRangePickerWrapper")
        .classList.add(" another-class");
    }}
  />
  {openIngestDatepicker && (
    <div className="z-intex999">
      <DateRangePicker
        onChange={(item) => setIngestDate([item.selection])}
        showSelectionPreview={true}
        moveRangeOnFirstSelection={false}
        months={2}
        ranges={ingestDate}
        direction="horizontal"
      />
    </div>
  )}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".rdrDateRangePickerWrapper")
    .forEach(element => element.classList.add('another-class'));
```